# SELECT a time between two times range

Tags: mysql

I want to select some rows that match a certain hour interval. So I tried doing this but it doesn't work

```
SELECT * 
  FROM geocoord 
 WHERE ID = "3574" 
   AND startTime < TIME_FORMAT("00:00:00","%h %m %s") 
   AND endTime > TIME_FORMAT("05:00:00","%h %m %s")
```

What I want to do is select all the rows where the ID is 3574 that match between 12 AM to 5 AM

Comment: We need more information, preferably your table structure. What is 'startTime' defined as?

Comment: @Piku is defined as time

Comment: Haven't you got your logic backwards? A time less than midnight and greater than 5am returns everything between 5am and midnight. I.e 5am, 6am, 7am ... which is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: By "doesn't work" do you mean you're getting an error? I'd imagine that `ID` is an integer, which implies you don't need quotes. If it is a character then you should be using the correct quotes, `'`. Also, what format is `starttime` and `endtime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try out

```
SELECT * 
FROM geocoord 
WHERE ID="3574" 
AND startTime < TIME_FORMAT("00:00:00","%H:%i:%s") 
AND endTime > TIME_FORMAT("05:00:00","%H:%i:%s")
```